# Make a domain target two servers depending ont he port

Tags: iis, dns

I have a older server with SMTP configured and I've bought a faster server.

I want to make this new server the targeted domain and the older server a SMTP server.

But I want the domain to target both servers depending on the port beeing used.

How can I do that?

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "targeted domain"? Why is this question tagged with IIS when you're using SMTP? (I know IIS has an SMTP server built-in but it's awful and no-one should be using it - and it's intended for outbound mail, not inbound).

Comment: I have only the basics course in IIS and Windows Server, therefore I'm really having a hard time right now.

I so sorry by the confusion.

What I mean by the "targeted server" is the server that has the IP that the domain points into using a A.

The older server is a third party Linux/PHP server while the new server is a Windows Server wich we have total control, so we can use any languege we want, therefore is far better for simple development.

Comment: Right now I'm trying to use IIS to redirect some requests to the older server, but I don't really know how to do any of this so please help me out unstead of just downvoting like the other questions I've made.

Answer (score 1):

Who will do this is "NAT" (Network Address Translation).

How do you receive your internet?
In general we use:

```
Internet -> Modem -> Firewall -> Servers
```

If your scenery is like that, your configuration must be made on firewall.
Deppending you firewall solution this configuration can be called "publish rule" or "nat rule".

Comment: My server is a virtual machine hosted at Azure. I've resarched how to do it in Azure but I've haven't found anything, could you send me a link or anything? Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Azure it's simple, you just need to create a Load balance to do it.

As you have 2 server you need another element to receive the traffic and forward.

To it works, all users must use LoadBalance IP (You need to adjust your DNS record).

You need to configure the LoadBalance to forward the traffic to apropriate server based on port requested.

Official documentation can help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-port-forwarding-portal

Take care about MX change, maybe not necessary:
All domains must have at least 1 MX record, it's who will manager email requests.
If you split your mail server just for a webmail porpose for example, maybe not necessary change the MX record.

If you prefere, share here your complet situation and we'll try to help with more precision.

Comment: The complete situation: At first, the company wich I work for right now wasn't meant to development. Therefore they paid for a thid party to host our website, email and domain. After a while they hired me for web development and I wanted to target (CNAME) our server as webserver but with some ports pointing to their server.

Comment: Since the third party server isn't within my v-net, for what I've understood reading the documentation, I'm not able to use load balancer neither firewall.

Comment: I'm not sure about use a external IP, but, you can use a your server and make a redirect on server level to another server:
If Port 25: Handle locally
If port 26: Redirect to X.Y.Z.1

Answer (score 0):

I've done some more resarch and I've found that in the DNS server I could create a MX registry targeting the other server, is that right?

https://support.google.com/a/answer/48090